# PhpStorm: How do I change a mistaken acceptance of autocomplete

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

I am sure this is on SO but I am danged if I can find it - sorry.

**What is the keyboard shortcut to change an autocompletion you have accidentally accepted?**

---

PhpStorm has great autocompletion - except sometimes it goes bonkers.

For example: Working with Bootstrap HTML in PHP files, previously if I typed <kbd>c</kbd>  <kbd>o</kbd>  <kbd>l</kbd> it would autocomplete to `col-sm-12` or something like that.

Recently it started to put `collapse` at the top of the list - something I have used less than 5% of the number of times I have used `col-`. I "automatically" hit `enter` and ...

This no doubt sounds trivial but I am slow enough typing code and autocomplete has been a boon which I use - well - automatically. I type a few characters and hit enter. It is ingrained in me.

I am sure  I remember there being a shortcut to change your mind after you have accepted a completion in error.

Anyone?

Comment: Not sure about that TBH. The only thing that comes into my mind is Undo `Ctrl+Z` and then invoke code completion manually (`Ctrl+Space` on Windows/Linux).

Comment: Its worse than I said. I type the col then to "force" the correct answer I type dash and the **** puts in `collapse-` so EVERY time I have to down arrow to col-. Oh well I just will work around it I guess. I'll try the `ctrl space` and see if that works. Thanks for the thought. EDIT Well well the  `ctrl space` immediately forced the desired output. Excellent!

Comment: Glad to hear that you have it now working .. but I'm still confused at what the issue is (your new description from the comment  actually). can you share a screenshot of your Code Completion settings + small video of how it works for you (that `col-` that ends up in `collapse-`). `collapse` is a CSS property and `col-sm-12` is a class name (different context)... I guess it's an Emmet in action here for partial prop completion.